# Echo element from php array

Tags: php, json, twitter, feed

Can someone tell me how I can loop through the below array?

http://pastebin.com/rhaF5Zdi

I've tried with out luck:

```
$_data = json_decode($_data);
foreach ( $_data as $tweet )
{
    echo "{$tweet->text}\n";
}
```

thanks

ps: im follwoing this php script.
http://mikepultz.com/2013/06/mining-twitter-api-v1-1-streams-from-php-with-oauth/

hers another paste bin on the array. there seems to be multiple arrays happening
http://pastebin.com/dduzhpqY

Comment: Where is it coming from? Something went wrong decoding it, see those `=&gt;` everywhere? That doesn't look right... What errors are you getting?

Comment: Ah sorry my bad, copy and paste did something weird. I've updated the array data. thanks

Comment: Have you tried - echo $tweet->text . '\n'; ?

Comment: Just tried and it doesn't seem to work. If I print that I get the error message "Trying to get property of non-object" so i guessing its not an object but an array? so I tried $_data['text']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might be creating a PHP stnd object instead of an array

```
//this will create a php standard object
$objOfData=json_decode($json);
```

Instead Use the version below:  (**Notice the the 2nd parameter is TRUE**)

```
$associativeArray=json_decode($json, TRUE);
```

This will turn the object into an associative array and you can access fields like so:

```
$id=$associativeArray['id'];
```

More info here: [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: I think i'm doing in correctly but something must be wrong. ' $data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
                        if ($data)
                        {
                            // process it
                            $this->process_tweet($data);

                        }' then ' private function process_tweet($_data)
    {
        echo $_data['text'];
    }'

Answer (score 0):

The code in posted link is not JSON, but it is output of print_r() function. PHP has no invert function to print_r(), but on php.net in print_r() documentation's comments you can find some user-made functions which can read it.

For example this one:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php#93529

I hope it will help. Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using:

```
if(array_key_exists('text', $_data)){
        echo 'Tweet ID = '.$_data['id_str'];
        echo 'Tweet Text = '.$_data['text'];
        echo '<br /><br />';
    }
```

cheers